# Replace New CSS sprite with current CSS

Tags: html, css, templates, blogger

I'm facing some problem while applying my new custom css sprite to old (current) css coding. I'm confused that how can i replace new custom css sprite to current individual css images. So I've decided to ask a question to here the family of stackoverflow.

**

### New CSS Sprite

**

```css
.top-post {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.top-post li {
background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-FHy0Ggdh6bU/VFFLrVyU8xI/AAAAAAAAKvY/VvEasvdSOYc/s156/css-sprites-post-top.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;

display: inline-block;
width: 16px;
height: 20px;
}
.top-post li a {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.top-post li.time {
background-position: -4px 0;
}
.top-post li.admin {
background-position: -85px 0;
margin-left: 60px;
}
.top-post li.cate {
background-position: -137px 0;
margin-left: 28px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-post">
  <li class="time">
    <a href="#" title='Date and Time'></a>
  </li>
  <li class="admin">
    <a href="#" title="Author"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="cate">
    <a href="#" title='Categories'></a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Now please anybody tell me how and where i apply or replace this custom css sprite to default blogger template images.

Update:

**

### Replace with (current individual css images):

**

```css
.meta_date,.meta_author,.meta_comments,.meta_edit,.meta_categories,.meta_tags{padding:3px 0 3px 20px;background-position:left center;background-repeat:no-repeat}
.meta_date{background-image:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Qs7vcrvEtsQ/UvqEdy0-p2I/AAAAAAAAH48/FCbuf9BtTTA/s16/time.png)}
.meta_author{background-image:url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-FSweUHUzAjo/UvqEXLx3sfI/AAAAAAAAH2o/LZb88YPzPQk/s16/author.png)}
.meta_categories{background-image:url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FuigICeM7zU/TpeWPinXvRI/AAAAAAAAEWg/owY-Cta2Yn0/s1600/cat.png)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to add sprites images to your **current individual css images** in blogger then replace the blogger CSS code with below one...

```
.meta_date,.meta_author,.meta_comments,.meta_edit,.meta_categories,.meta_tags{padding:3px 0 3px 20px;background-position:left center;background-repeat:no-repeat}
.meta_date, .meta_author, .meta_categories{background-image:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-FHy0Ggdh6bU/VFFLrVyU8xI/AAAAAAAAKvY/VvEasvdSOYc/s156/css-sprites-post-top.png);}
.meta_date{background-position:-4px 0;}
.meta_author{background-position:-85px 0;}
.meta_categories{background-position:-137px 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking where to place your CSS?

You can either

1.)Go to Template--Customise--Advanced--Add css and paste your css there

2.)Go to template-Edit Html(make a backup 1st)-and paste your code before `]]></b:skin>` or `</b:skin>` tag ends

Comment: I want to replace this css sprite with the existing individual images in template..